# How can I use the Google meet APIs to retrieve the start and end time

Tags: laravel, google-api, google-meet

**Scenario:**
I scheduled a meeting from 12 PM to 1 PM, but it started at 12:30 PM and ended at 2 PM. The same thing happened again at 2:30 PM to 4 PM in the same meeting. Now, I want to know the actual time when the meeting happened. So for that I use https://developers.google.com/meet/api/guides/overview  Google Meet API. But I'm not able to enable Google Meet Service in Google cloud console.

I try to add scopes for this API https://developers.google.com/meet/api/reference/rest/v2beta/conferenceRecords.participants.participantSessions/list and it should be return participants session details but got 403 error.[image]